# Sum of a multiplication of two columns grouped by another column in an inner join of three tables returns wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Sum of a multiplication of two columns grouped by another column in an inner join of three tables returns wrong value.
Below are my three tables:

Table1:
[image]

Table2:

[image]

Table3:

[image]

My Query is as below:

```
SELECT c.price, c.quantity, SUM( c.quantity * c.price ) AS price, 
group_concat( a.rate
SEPARATOR '<br>' ) AS rates, c.hsn AS hsn
FROM tax_wa a
INNER JOIN tax_rate_class b ON a.tax_rate_id = b.tax_rate_id
INNER JOIN inv_item c ON b.tax_class_id = c.tax_class_id
WHERE c.invoice_id = '17'
GROUP BY c.hsn
```

And the result is:

[image]

But above one is not correct... To expain it, if you run the below query on the inv_item table (alone, with no joins) you get correct results:

```
SELECT price, quantity, sum( quantity * price )
FROM `inv_item`
WHERE invoice_id = '17'
GROUP BY hsn
```

Result is good:

[image]

Above result the wrong value calculated
if you add all

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(c.price),  SUM(c.quantity), SUM( c.quantity * c.price ) AS price, 
       group_concat( a.rate SEPARATOR '<br>' ) AS rates, c.hsn AS hsn
FROM tax_wa a INNER JOIN
     tax_rate_class b
     ON a.tax_rate_id = b.tax_rate_id INNER JOIN
     inv_item c
     ON b.tax_class_id = c.tax_class_id
WHERE c.invoice_id = 17
GROUP BY c.hsn;
```